# Width of html td

Tags: html, css

We have a table on html page which contains around 20 columns. We were not able to adjust the width of each `<td>` and later we found that since the page is too congusted with columns the browser(chrome and explorer) over rides the width property of `<td>` and pack the `<td>` blocks close to close. Is there a way to adjust the `<td>` width so that the `<td>` blocks are sufficiently apart.

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some code? you can set the `width` on `td`s you know

Comment: this link will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust a width of each column using `<Col>` tag. 
Example:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <col width="100">
  <col width="75">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Place</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Venkat</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>USA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<col width="100">` and `<col width="75">` will not affect because of setting `width="100%"` in `<table>`

Comment: You just try it and see.. :) <br/> It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

use CSS.

If you want to give same width to all `td` you can try the below code.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .mytable td,.mytable th{
        width:100px;
    }
</style>

<table border="1" class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Place</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Venkat</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>USA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if all `td` will have different sizes you can try the below code,

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .mytable .firstth{
        width:100px;
    }
    .mytable .secondth{
        width:250px;
    }
</style>

<table border="1" class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th class='firstth'>Name</th>
    <th class='secondth'>Place</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Venkat</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>USA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

most probably giving width to `th` will arrange the corresponding `td` properly.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jdp7v/